# Integration with Riemann Sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I wanted to try to perform a Riemann Sum for the following integral, but I got stuck in the middle.

$$\int_{-1}^0 e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

So the interval is $[-1, 0]$, and I chose $\Delta x = \dfrac{1}{n}$. In this way $x_i = \dfrac{i}{n}$ and
$$f(x_i) = e^{-(i/n)^2}$$

Here is where I got stuck because now I cannot manage this:

$$\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n e^{-(i/n)^2}$$

How can I proceed?

I thought of using Geometric Progression but I cannot understand how to.

Comment: Since this integral is nonelementary- expressible  in terms of the error function - you will not get a nice closed form for this or any equivalent Riemann sum

Comment: @FShrike Since my goal is to prove through Riemann Sum that the integral is positive, can I just point out instead that the sum would be a sum of positive terms, hence the integral will be positive? Even without manipulating the sum, or just by showing some terms (like choosing $n = 3$)?

Comment: If your goal is to show the integral is positive... it suffices to show that there is a parition of $[-1,0]$ where the lower sum is positive.  But that is easy for the simplest partition, $\{-1,0\}$ with $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the amended question in the comments, namely, “how does one show this integral is positive?”.

It’s an integral of a strictly positive function over a nondegenerate interval. You can very simply show this is positive without a specific calculation (which isn’t really possible in this case anyway). Use $e^{-x^2}\ge1/e$ so note that any partial Riemann sum, using any partition, shall give a sum greater than $1/e\cdot(0-(-1))=1/e$. Therefore the limit of the sums along any partitions whose mesh vanishes - the Riemann integral, by definition - shall be a limit of a sequence of numbers all greater than $1/e$. The final limit must then be $\ge1/e>0$ by basic limit properties.